# IIS 7 URL Rewrite QueryString

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I have old links like this

```
/folder/page/(dynamic q)
```

I want to redirect to a new links

```
/newfolder/newpage?q=(dynamic q)
```

how can I do this

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do this with the IIS rewrite module and ran into a couple of problems when i found out about [HelliconAPE](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/). This program enables you to use normal .htaccess files as you would on an apache server.